# Enforcing scrollToTop behavior using React Router

Tags: react-router, redux

I would like to have the user's scroll position default to the top of the page upon transitions.

For example, clicking on a `<Link>` element on the footer pushes the user into view that's scrolled all the way down, where the footer is.

Is there an option to set all transitions to display the new component from the top?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**React Router versions <4**

You can also simply add an `onUpdate` attribute to your `<Router>` like so:

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={history}>
  // routes
</Router>
```

**React Router version 4**

In the new React Router version, you can create a ScrollToTop component like this (adapted from the [docs here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration)):

```
// ScrollToTop.js    
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

And then you use it by adding it immediately below your BrowserRouter/Router component like this:

```
// App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop'

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>{' '}
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: You should also reset keyboard focus at the same time as scrolling to top. I wrote a thing to take care of it: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router

Answer (score 6):

You need to import the `scroll-behavior` lib, designed for use with react router. Here's how you use it:

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import useScrollToTop from 'scroll-behavior/lib/useScrollToTop';

const history = useScrollToTop(createHistory)();
```

Then pass the `history` object as the history prop to your `Router`.

The above code snippet - modified to import `useScrollToTop` instead of `useStandardScroll` - was taken from here:
https://github.com/rackt/scroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you followed React router docs (and Sia's answer) but found yourself with this error:

```
Invariant Violation: ScrollToTop.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

try to wrap everything inside ScrollToTop into one `<div>`:

```
<Router>
  <ScrollToTop>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>{' '}
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </div>
  </ScrollToTop>
</Router>
```